# Opening plastic soda bottles on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, food, melacha-creative-work, yom-tov

In regards to opening plastic soda bottles on Shabbos I'm sure everyone knows [there is](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5757/beshal.html) a [maklokes](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/587) in this. Is the same maklokes applicable on Yom Tov, or is Yom Tov different so that according to everyone it is [muter](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) to open the bottles? (My sofek (doubt) is based on there being a [heter](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/585) to do some [malachos](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/610) on Yom Tov l'tzrich ochel nefesh (for the purpose of food for humans).)

Comment: Wouldn't it depend what the reasons of those who prohibit are? If so, why aren't you including those details in your question when they seem extremely relevant?

Comment: What maklokes? I quote from your link: "It is permissible to unscrew a plastic cap, even if it separates and leaves a ring around the bottle neck." The only bottle cap with a question is the metal one that has tabs that break on the bottom when you unscrew it.

Comment: Certainly it would depend on the reasons for those that say it's ossur. Sorry for not listing those I simply pointed out that there is a maklokes in this. Those who prohibit it are for a few reasons. Either m'chatek or making a cli, etc. In regards to Yom Tov we permit the malachos "m'lisha v'eliech" in the seder of the malachos. My question is do these chashashes in regards to Shabbos fall into the category of malachos that are permitted on Shabbos or are ossur. Perhaps there are other points to take into account that someone could point out to me.

Comment: I dont do it cause its tearing. 
But we deduced that biased off of the plain meaning of the prohibition and didnt factor in later heters by non authoritative rabbi's. But i do have to admit that im from a school of thought that goes with the stringent approach in most cases if there is a doubt.

Comment: @Ariel In his defense, that isn't his link. See the revision history. To the best of my knowledge he is right about there being a machloket on the matter.

Comment: In Eretz Yisrael the maklokes is quoted that R' Shlomo Zalman Aurbach was matir and R' Eliyashuv held that it's ossur (to open the plastic caps on Shabbos.)

Answer (score 1):

Some *poskim* have indeed raised concerns when opening a bottle cap on Shabbat or Yom Tov, e.g., turning the cap into a receptacle (*kli*), completing the formation of a utensil (*make bepatish*), tearing (*korea*) and more (see e.g., [here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5772-beshalach/)).

Shemirat Shabbat Kehilchata (9:22), after explaining one cannot remove the bottle cap of a bottle if that act converts it into a usable top which can be replaced and removed at will, writes

> **The various rules set out above are equally applicable on both Shabbat
>   and Yom Tov.**

And indeed the *melachot* possibly relevant to opening a soda bottle cap are not part of those permitted on Yom Tov for the sake of *ochel nefesh* (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20439/11501) for the list).

R Doniel Neustadt ([here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5772-beshalach/)) also doesn't note a difference, nor does [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2011/09/14/opening-bottlescans-on-shabbos/).

For the avoidance of doubt, and as noted by Chacham Nisan in comments, there are many *poskim* who are lenient regarding soda bottles on both Shabbat and Yom Tov.