# Borer and Grinding on Yom Tov - and other Melachoth that are Ochel Nefesh

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, melacha-creative-work

Which [Melachoth are prohibited on Shabbath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activities_prohibited_on_Shabbat) but are permissible to perform on Yom Tov because of the [exception of Ochel Nefesh](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Which_Melachot_are_forbidden_on_Yom_Tov%3F)?  Famously, cooking and carrying in the public domain are allowed, yet igniting a flame from scratch is not.  Furthermore, some other actions that would seem to be Ochel Nefesh [are also prohibited](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbosVI-4.pdf).  What else is allowed?  Are [Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activities_prohibited_on_Shabbat#Sorting.2FPurification) and [Grinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activities_prohibited_on_Shabbat#Grinding) on the list?

I am also fairly certain that there's a difference between Ashkenazi practice and Sepharadi practice in some instances. Please provide sources for each.

(Please don't list smoking as permitted as cooking but should be prohibited because of danger, or other such exceptions to the exceptions. I'm looking for general categories of Melachah, not unique subcategories or specific types of actions.  If a category is permitted only under certain circumstances, such as squeezing a lemon on a solid but not into a liquid, which is permissible on Shabbath anyway, that should be noted.)

Comment: Igniting a new flame _is_ permitted deorayta because of ochel nefesh. We just say it's a problem of Nolad.

Comment: @DoubleAA So, if someone did, one could benefit BeDi'Avad from the action?

Comment: It would be a rabbinic and not a biblical violation. Was it Meizid or Shogeg? See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14770/759 The more interesting Nafka Minah IMO is that driving a car is only derabanan, which could be applicable in possible kavod habriyot or choleh she'ein bo sakana cases. Obviously CYLOR before doing that :)

Comment: @DoubleAA That. (Limmud.) Is. Awesome.

Comment: @DoubleAA, It was also the first thing that popped into my head when you made your comment.

Comment: I think grinding comes from healing (making a poultice), not from cooking.  Since healing is still prohibited on yontiv, you cannot grind on yontiv.  Borer, however, comes from cooking (sorting bad from good grains), so it is permitted.

Comment: @charles koppelman I think you have it backwards. http://www.ou.org/chagim/shabbat/thirtynine.htm#22 Healing is prohibited, lest you come to grind healing herbs.

Comment: BTW just to source what I said above, see the first Mishna Berura on OC 502 (or assorted other commentaries ad loc).

Comment: Generally, you may do borer even not miyad, not biyad, and p'soles from the ochel. The following is an oversimplified principle that is by no means sufficient to understanding what you may grind: Any type of grinding that is normally done for immediate consumption is allowed. See OC 504.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Zoreah (Sowing) - forbidden
2. Choresh (Plowing) - forbidden
3. Kotzair (Reaping) - forbidden
4. M'amair  (Gathering) - forbidden
5. Dush (Threshing) – forbidden
6. Zoreh (Winnowing) - forbidden
7. **Borer (Sorting ) – [generally] permitted**
8. Tochain (Grinding) – forbidden
9. Miraked (Sifting) - forbidden
10. **Lush (Kneading) - permitted**
11. **Ofeh / Bishul (Baking/cooking) - permitted**
12. Gozez (Shearing) - forbidden
13. Melabain  (Whitening) - forbidden
14. Menafetz (Disentangling, Combing) - forbidden
15. Tzovayah (Dyeing) – forbidden
16. Toveh (Spinning) - forbidden
17. Maisach (Mounting the warp) - forbidden
18. Oseh Beit Batai Neirin (Setting two heddles) - forbidden
19. Oraig (Weaving) - forbidden
20. Potzai'ah (Separating threads) - forbidden
21. Koshair (Tying a knot) - forbidden
22. Matir (Untying a knot) - forbidden
23. Tofair (Sewing) – forbidden
24. Ko'reah (Tearing) - forbidden
25. Tzud (Trapping) - forbidden
26. **Shochet (Slaughtering) - permitted**
27. **Mafshit (Skinning) - permitted**
28. **M'abaid (Salting/tanning process) - permitted**
29. Mesharteit (Tracing lines) - forbidden
30. Memacheik (Smoothing / scraping) - forbidden
31. Mechateich (Cutting to shape) - forbidden
32. Kotaiv (Writing two or more letters) - forbidden
33. Mochaik (Erasing two or more letters) - forbidden
34. Boneh (Building) - forbidden
35. Soiser (Demolishing) - forbidden
36. **Mechabeh (Extinguishing) – only for actual “ochel nefesh”**
37. **Ma'avir (Kindling) – permitted**
38. Makeh B'Patish (Striking the final blow) – forbidden
39. **Hotza'ah – (Transferring from domain to domain) - permitted**

(Based on the [first chapter](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46542&st=&pgnum=41) of Nitey Gavriel Hilchos Yom Tov (Chelek Aleph). List of melachos from [here](http://www.torahtots.com/torah/39melachot.htm)).

Comment: What sort of extinguishing is permitted? Ie., can you provide an example of "actual 'ochel nefesh'" to which this would apply?

Comment: @SethJ Perhaps if your roast is on fire, you can put it out.

Comment: this is all derived in at the end of the first chapter of bietzah in the yerushalmi

Comment: I think you mean _mav'ir_.