# Should driving be permitted on Yom Tov for a choleh she-ein bo sakanah?

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, choleh-sick, derabanan

Since *hav'arah* (i.e. sparking a new fire) is only *de-rabbanan* on *yom tov* (according to some opinions), should there be more halakhic leeway for driving to obtain medical care on a holiday (not on *Shabbath*)?

Why or why not? Please cite your sources.

Comment: Havarah is only derabbanan on Yom Tov? News to me.

Comment: @Micha Berger - Well, maybe you should get out more. The nature of the prohibition is, at the very least, debated by the *poseqim*. See the discussions of this point on *ein mossi'in*. And, from my own persepctive, it seems that the Rambam holds that it is a *shevuth*. The Raavad argues that it is an actual *melakhah* of *molid*. Shavua` tov.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20430/borer-and-grinding-on-yom-tov-and-other-melachoth-that-are-ochel-nefesh#comment48235_20430 Why would you think driving would be prohibited for a ChShEBS?

Comment: Re "_hav'arah_ (i.e. sparking a new fire)": _Hav'ara_ is _mutar_ for _tzorech yom tov_ AFAIK; the prohibition on a new fire is not _hav'ara_ but _molid_ (which, as you note, is _d'rabanan_). I may well be mistaken, though.

Comment: Havarah, molid, whatever. Using one word over the other already implies a position.

Comment: The Chida deduces from the Rambam that molid is derabbanan on Yom Tov, but most do not (eg the Kaf haChaim), and most rishonim don't even hint at the possibility. This was asked and answered at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22289/can-i-light-a-new-fire-on-yom-tovB

Comment: See the Rambam, Hil Yom Tov 1:5. And the Raavad's reply, it sheds light on what the Raavad is saying here.


The Yerushalmi has a machloqes whether the "could have been done before" rule applies act-wise or melakhah wise -- do we allow any food prep that could not have been done as well before YT, or any melakhah that typically couldn't, even in cases where

Comment: So, what exactly are you saying here? Are you trying to prove that you were correct in your initial [sarcastic] remark? Or are you trying to prove that my understanding of the Rambam is incorrect? Either way, I think that you should answer the question. And if you want to answer the question of whether it is a Biblical or Rabbinic prohibition, then you should post an answer on that question. Kol tuv.

Comment: @MichaBerger - There are, in fact, many (composed of both *rishonim* and *aharonim*) who understand the Rambam this way and are *poseq* accordingly, not the least which is the Radvaz (שו"ת סי' אתקכ"ג), who maintains that the only reason is *dawqah* because of *hakhanah mi-ba-`erev* to the point that one who is held captive or in a *midbar* and never had the chance to prepare a fire before YT, may do so on YT through whatever means are available and use it to cook, bake, etc. Even though the *gemara* use the term *molidh*, it is debated whether this was to be taken literally...

Comment: ...In the commentary of Rav Yosef Qafih z"l (see *Hilkhoth Shevitath Yom Tov* 4:1, *oth* א), he explains - in light of the explicit *Yerushalmi* that the reason that Rambam did NOT use the term *molidh* as was in the *gemara* (thus spurring the comment of the Raavad) was because it would only serve to be misleading in this case. He says that *molidh* is being used in a more general sense of *le-holidh* or *le-hamssi* ("to bring forth"), and NOT in the sense of *Hilkhoth Shabbat*. His explanation there is completely thorough and leaves no doubt as to the Rambam's intention. Kol tuv.

Comment: @MichaBerger - One notable modern-day *poseq* who [apparently] understands the Rambam this way is Rav Yitzchak Abadi, who holds that if one lit or started their oven before YT with the intention of preparing it before YT, if it should go out for any reason (or, more commonly, due to a safety feature of the oven) - then one is allowed to relight it on YT for the purposes of *okhel nefesh*. Kol tuv.