# Is lighting a new flame on Yom Tov a Biblical or Rabbinic prohibition?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, yom-tov, derabanan, fire-burning

Is lighting a completely new fire on Yom Tov a Biblical or a Rabbinic prohibition?

Please cite your sources.

Comment: This is a machloket Rishonim. Most poskim nowadays assume it's a rabbinic prohibition IINM. This is a pretty poor post, though.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22289/759

Comment: @DannySchoemann How is this a duplicate? The other question doesn't ask whether it's a biblical or rabbinic prohibition