# Lighting from a pre-existing flame on 1st night Yom Tov if saying brachos first?

Tags: minhag, blessing, yom-tov, candle-lighting

[Some](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20243/beracha-on-lighting-yom-tov-candles-before-or-after) have the custom to say the bracha before kindling lights on (erev) Yom Tov. The linked page claims in one place that this is allowed because we don't receive Yom Tov with the bracha, and in another place because "there is no problem of lighting a candle on yom tov, therefore better to make the bracha first [as is customary]."
(The first explanation is not sourced; the second is attributed to the  Magen Avraham.)
I read in my own source that the second of these is the reason.

So:

1. According to the second reason, shouldn't we then absolutely light the candles from a pre-existing flame--even (erev) the first night of Yom Tov--if we are doing it in this order? (It is [prohibited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64589/is-lighting-a-new-flame-on-yom-tov-a-biblical-or-rabbinic-prohibition) to light a new flame on Yom Tov; however, one [may](https://www.ou.org/holidays/rosh-hashanah/36050/) light from a pre-existing flame. If there is any sense at all in which one ushers in Yom Tov with the bracha--as this explanation allows--one would then need to light candles only from a pre-existing flame. One could, for example, strike the match, make the bracha, and then light the candles.)
2. According to the first, might there be anyway be a reason to light from a pre-existing flame because of marit ayin? (In other words, that others might think one can create a new flame on Yom Tov because this was done subsequent to the bracha.)

Comment: How does one light candles from a non-preexisting flame? I don't follow what the other option is. Do you mean a candle with some sort of self-igniting wick (like http://google.com/patents/US7473282)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, pre- _yom tov_, not pre- the candle's being lit. Perhaps the question could be clearer, since apparently you found it hard to understand.

Comment: @msh210 Does that mean the suggestion is to say the blessing with no flame, then light a match, then light a candle? Sounds like a Hefsek, or at least Oveir deOveir. I don't know that anyone could sanction such a practice in general, even ignoring the issue of making a new fire on Yom Tov.

Comment: @msh210 I'd really like to learn which reason is correct. In order to do so, is my only option to make a bounty on the other question? I maintain that that question does not address it

Comment: I think so, yes. (And the answers may not address it satisfactorily but I think the question does.) See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers