# Why are we allowed to light candles for second day yom tov if it is not ochel nefesh?

Tags: yom-tov, candle-lighting, fire-burning, ochel-nefesh

With these questions ([1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30864/why-allowed-on-yom-tov), [2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20430/borer-and-grinding-on-yom-tov-and-other-melachoth-that-are-ochel-nefesh)) as partial background I still do not understand the permission to light candles, with a blessing, on the second day of Yom Tov if that lighting is not for *ochel nefesh*.

Comment: How is this different from the question you linked to? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30864/759 Are you wondering why we apply _mitokh_ (the leap discussed in that link) here? Are you asking specifically about the candles lit at night with a blessing?

Comment: I think it's quite clear why this is different from the linked question. The linked question is asking why "ochel nefesh" includes things other than food prepartion; this question is asking why we are allowed to do something (lighting candles) that is not ochel nefesh. I don't know if either of the two premises is wrong, but that shouldn't be a correction that requires closing this question. (I personally would really like to know the answer to this.)

Comment: To expand on my edit comment: because the original poster is no longer on Mi Yodeya, and the question was only slightly unclear, and another MY user expressed interest in having this question answered, I have edited the question to improve clarity in order to vote to reopen in the review queue. cc @SAH